# What phonetic notation or transliteration style Google uses for showing the transliteration of the Bangla Words in Google Translate?

Tags: google-translate, transliteration, phonetics

Google provides a transliteration of the word the user types in Google Translate (as highlighted in the image below)[image: as highlighted in the image below].

Can anyone please confirm with evidence like a blog or site or a paper that mentions what phonetic notation or transliteration style Google use for showing the transliteration of the Bangla Words? Is it the International Phonetic Alphabet ([IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)) or International Alphabet of Sanskrit Transliteration ([IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration)), or the National Library at Kolkata Romanization ([NLK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Library_at_Kolkata_romanisation))?

[Here is a thread](https://support.google.com/translate/thread/41160492?hl=en&msgid=41208759) from April 20, 2020, which says Google Translate uses North American Phonetic Alphabet system.